# Problems using x.length within for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having problems trying to dynamically generate an HTML table based on input (column/row) values.

When I hardcode the values in the loop below (i.e. instead of using the prompt), it creates the correct number of cells. However, when using x.length within the loop, something isn't working correctly.

**works correctly:**

function createTable() {

```
    // declare variables
    var body = document.body,
        table = document.createElement('table');


    // Begin creating table
    // for each row
    for(var r = 0; r < 8; r++) {

        // create row
        var tr = table.insertRow();

        // for each column
        for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++) {

            // create column
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Cell'));

        }
    }

    // append table to body
    body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable();
```

**does not create correct cells based on variable input**

function createTable() {

```
    // declare variables
    var body = document.body,
        table = document.createElement('table'),
        rows = prompt("enter rows"),
        columns = prompt("enter columns");


    // Begin creating table
    // for each row
    for(var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {

        // create row
        var tr = table.insertRow();

        // for each column
        for(var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {

            // create column
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Cell'));

        }
    }

    // append table to body
    body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

`rows` and `columns` are strings, that's the only reason why they have a `.length`. You seem to want to use them as [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) numbers, without any lengths:

```
var body = document.body,
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    rows = parseInt(prompt("enter rows"), 10),
    columns = parseInt(prompt("enter columns"), 10);

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var tr = table.insertRow();
    for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Cell'));
    }
}
body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Is there a parse method?

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger: You can use `parseInt`, `Number`, unary `+`, … Actually even using them as strings should work, as you only compare them with the *numbers* `r` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt(rows)` and `parseInt(columns)`. This functions return an integer but you must check if the input is really an string-represented integer value.